# Flutter Riverpod updating state issue

Tags: flutter, riverpod

The state is not updating while the value in the print statement is updating.
I don't know if I had used the correct way of the Counter class or not please help me.

here is my code :

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';


class numbers{
  int value1 = 0;
  int value2 = 0;
}

class Counter extends StateNotifier<numbers> {
  Counter(super.state);
  void add1()
  {
    state.value1++;
    print(state.value1.toString() + ' FromClass');
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import 'Counter.dart';

final counterProvider = StateNotifierProvider<Counter, numbers>((ref)=>Counter(numbers()));

void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context,WidgetRef ref) {
    var count = ref.watch(counterProvider.notifier).state.value1;
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,children: [Center(child: Container(child: Text(count.toString()),),),
      ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
        ref.read(counterProvider.notifier).state.value1++;
        print(ref.read(counterProvider.notifier).state.value1);
        //print(count.readValue1());
      }, child: Text('+'))],),),);
  }
}
```

Make the state updating after pressing + button

Comment: `ref.watch(counterProvider.notifier)`.  You are watching the notifier, not the provider.  Watching the notifier does almost nothing (unless the notifier itself is replaced, which is rare).

Comment: Still not working after change these :                                                                        var count = ref.watch(counterProvider).value1;  ref.read(counterProvider).value1++;

Comment: Correct.  You should not be mutating state outside of the provider.  Put a method on the notifier to mutate value1 by assigning to state or by calling notifyListeners().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I converted your `Numbers' model. First of all, it must be immutable and with correctly redefined ==/hashCode. To make such models easily, take a closer look at the [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) package.

```dart
@immutable
class Numbers {
  const Numbers({this.value1 = 0, this.value2 = 0});

  final int value1;
  final int value2;

  Numbers copyWith({
    int? value1,
    int? value2,
  }) {
    return Numbers(
      value1: value1 ?? this.value1,
      value2: value2 ?? this.value2,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is Numbers &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          value1 == other.value1 &&
          value2 == other.value2;

  @override
  int get hashCode => value1.hashCode ^ value2.hashCode;
}
```

Your `Counter` class will look like this:

```dart
final counterProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<Counter, Numbers>((ref) => Counter(const Numbers()));

class Counter extends StateNotifier<Numbers> {
  Counter(super.state);
  void add1() {
    state = state.copyWith(value1: state.value1 + 1);
    print('${state.value1} Counter.add1');
  }
}
```

And the interface is converted as follows:

```dart
class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final count1 = ref.watch(counterProvider.select((value) => value.value1));

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Center(child: Text(count1.toString())),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  ref.read(counterProvider.notifier).add1();
                  print(ref.read(counterProvider.notifier).state.value1);
                },
                child: const Text('+'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I purposely used `select` so that changing the value of `value2` would not trigger a rebuild. If you need to keep track of the entire state of `Numbers` use a simple `ref.wacth(counterProvider)` in the `build` method:

```dart
final Numbers counter = ref.watch(counterProvider);
counter.value1;
```